# use custom field value as featured image

Tags: custom-field, post-thumbnails

I know this has been investigated before but no one has given a solution. Besides, I have not enough Stack-reputation to add comments, so I have to ask a new question.

I want to use a post's custom-field ("fieldname") value as featured image.
I would like to create one single function-to-fit-all.
I come from this, but with no luck:

```
add_filter('get_the_post_thumbnail', function($html) {$post = get_post();
if (! $post) { return $html; }
if (! in_array($post->post_type, array('fieldname-one', 'fieldname-two'), true)) { return $html; }
$newThumbnail = filter_var( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'fieldname-one', 'fieldname-two', true), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );
if($newThumbnail) { $html = '<img src="' . esc_url($newThumbnail) . '" alt="" />'; }
return $html;
});
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction? Thank you

Comment: This custom image will show only front end? Will it also show on featured image section of post edit screen?

Comment: What you want is possible, but it's not going to be simple. And instead of trying to make it, try to do something like: create a function which retrieves the custom field value and returns a custom featured image HTML, and then use that function instead of `get_the_post_thumbnail()` when retrieving the featured image. Have a good day.

Comment: how does it work here on Stack? why have the previous answers been deleted? Anyway, creating a function that retrieves the field is what I have been trying so far, with no luck. e.g.<br>`add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', function($html) {
    $post = get_post();
    if (! $post) { return $html; }
    if (! in_array($post->post_type, array('company'), true)) { return $html; }    $newThumbnail = filter_var( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'FeaturedImage', true), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL );
    if($newThumbnail) { $html = '<img src="' . esc_url($newThumbnail) . '" alt="" />'; }
    return $html;
});
`

Comment: You say it's not simple but here's another splendid solution to the problem: https://pastebin.com/34WFEMXd it just doesn't work on my site:

Comment: another one: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/216264/automatically-set-featured-image-the-same-as-the-ogi-that-is-set-in-a-custom